# PostgreSQL: data type smaller than smallint?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a data type smaller than smallint (16bit)? I need a column with only numbers from 1 to 31 so i think that 5bits are enough and I do not want to waste space with the overhead of 11bit per tuple.

Comment: You might find the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090138/is-it-possible-to-store-a-1-byte-number-in-postgres helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) there is no such 1 byte integer so I think the best way is to use small int. If you don't consider to do any math operations you can also use just varchar(2) (but this is not the best idea).

Answer (score 2):

This is an actual concern? How much disk and memory is being wasted? Are you prepared for any possible slowdowns or code changes necessitated by such a change to your datatype?

If positive, take a look at the [bit string types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html).

Comment: In PostgreSQL, a 5-bit bitstring takes 6 bytes--1 byte for the value plus 5 bytes of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you need 31 *values*, not 31 numbers, you can use CHAR(1) and a CHECK() constraint.

```
your_column char(1) not null
  check (your_column in ('a','b','c'...'z','1','2','3','4','5'))
```

But I don't think that's a great idea. (5-bit "types" would often be padded to an 8-bit boundary anyway.)